# Convert and Operation Not working as expected. Ignoring Year value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have the following code:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), TimeCard_Date, 101) < 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), dateadd(dd,-3,getdate()), 101)
```

The Original `TimeCard_Date` value = 2018-06-01

The `GetDate()` return = 11/14/2017

Can anyone assist as to why it thinks the `Timecard_Date` value set for June  2018 is less than the `GetDate()` minus 3 days value?

Answer (score 0):

When you convert, it converts to a varchar datatype.  `06/01/2018` is less than `11/14/2017` as a varchar since it is an alphabetical (or by number?) comparison.  If you compare by date, the comparison is by the date datatype, which is as you expect.

You can change your code to:
`TimeCard_Date < dateadd(dd,-3,getdate())`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert DATETIME to VARCHAR in order to compare dates. Just use:

```
TimeCard_Date < DATEADD(dd,-3,GETDATE())
```

On the other hand, if you ever have to convert them to do it, you have to standarize the format (yyyyMMdd). You can check the FORMAT function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql